# Laravel 10 always returns null when trying to read a cookie value

Tags: laravel

I have a function inside a controller where I set a value for `oa.action` cookie:

```
public function setActionCookie($action)
    {
        $actionCookie = cookie("oa.action", $action, 30, '/', null, true, false, false, 'None');
        Cookie::queue($actionCookie);
    }
```

Everything works when I use the Inspector panel, `$action` always has a value but when I try to output cookies values with `dd($request->cookie());`, I always get `"oa_action" => null`

Any idea why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should avoid dots on [cookie names](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.setcookie.php#120794).
The PHP transforms the dot `.` in underscore `_`.

And [Laravel](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/responses#attaching-cookies-to-responses) uses the PHP's native `setcookie` method.